# $\lambda < 0 \land \left(A^2+B^2\right) \cos \left(2 \sqrt{\lambda } x\right)+2 A B \sinh \left(2 \sqrt{-\lambda } x\right)\leq 0 \implies A = B = 0$

Tags: inequality

I was solving an eigenvalue problem and ultimately ended up with having to prove

$$\lambda < 0 \land (A, B) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \land \left(A^2+B^2\right) \cos \left(2 \sqrt{\lambda } x\right)+2 A B \sinh \left(2 \sqrt{-\lambda } x\right)\leq 0 \implies A = B = 0$$

However, I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Are $A, B$ real numbers? For $x=0$ you get $A^2+B^2\le0$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the theorem I'm trying to prove implies that they have to be real numbers. I added that to the question. Is there a way to prove it for all $x$ (not just $0$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one imaginary argument; I get
$$  \cos it = \cosh t $$

which you need for $\cos 2 \sqrt \lambda x$ since you say $\lambda < 0$

$$ \left(A^2+B^2\right) \cosh \left(2 \sqrt{-\lambda } x\right)+2 A B \sinh \left(2 \sqrt{-\lambda } x\right)\leq 0 $$

Name $t = 2 \sqrt{-\lambda} x$ (which is real)  so that we are looking at
$$ (A^2 + B^2 ) \cosh t + 2AB \sinh t $$
Note that  $$ | \sinh t  | < \cosh t $$ and
$$ \sinh t > - \cosh t $$
$$ (A^2 + B^2 ) \cosh t + 2AB \sinh t \geq (A^2 + B^2 ) \cosh t - 2|AB| \cosh t$$
$$ (A^2 + B^2 ) \cosh t + 2AB \sinh t \geq (|A| - |B| )^2 \cosh t \geq (|A| - |B| )^2$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Complex_trigonometric_definitions

Comment: Oh, right, imaginary numbers can't be compared, so the only way to have the inequality true is if the LHS is 0. Thanks!

Comment: @Leponzo no. You need to correct the expression, it is actually real.